# Stand-alone ASP.NET monitoring tool

Tags: .net, monitoring, asp.net

I'd like to find a stand-alone monitoring tool that delivers similar features to [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/) which can monitor performance of a ASP.NET IIS web sites, breaking down response times by:

- client rendering
- network latency
- clr processing
- and SQL Server queries.

Problem with New Relic is that sites monitored by New Relic need access to New Relic's network.

Can anyone recommend monitoring tools that offer similar features but can be fully hosted within a private network?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please specify what features you are looking for. Not everybody is familiar with New Relic and someone could recommend a tool that offers some features of it but not others but won't know if they are the ones you are interested in. Also, please state your budget for this tool.

Comment: Well I took text that was already in the original submission and put them into bullet points.  I also added ASP.NET web sites, I believe New Relic can do PHP and others as well, however I'm interested in monitoring tools for ASP.NET / IIS

Comment: Great, could you give us your budget for this tool? Does it need to be gratis? If you are willing to pay for a solution, how much?

Comment: I'd be wanting a free evaluation.  In terms of budget, I wouldn't say the sky's the limit however it needn't be gratis, .